# Waiting for folders to be created to avoid 'Not found' errors using PnPJS

Tags: spfx, pnpjs

I am using PnPJS to create folders in SharePoint within a SPFX WebPart.  I'm having random issues when creating a bunch of folders when some of them return an error of 'Not Found'.  For example:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [500]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2130247139, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"(null) \"sites/MySite/Shared Documents/Assignment/testFolder\" not found."}}}
```

I've tried using setTimeout but this isn't working as I need to call the  web.folders.add method and then .getFolderByServerRelativePath method in sequence.  I think the second method is being called to quickly and the folder hasn't actually been created yet.  The code I'm using is:

```
  const rootFolderPromises = rootFolders.map(async (folder) => {
    const ifr: IFolderAddResult = await sp.web.folders.add(siteSRUrl + "/" + globalThis.libraryNameFull + "/" + folder.Title);

 
      const ifrProperties = await sp.web
        .getFolderByServerRelativePath(ifr.data.ServerRelativeUrl)
        .properties()
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      sp.web.lists.getByTitle("IndexNumbering").items.add({
        Title: ifr.data.Name,
        ItemUniqueId: ifr.data.UniqueId,
        DocLibRowId: ifrProperties.vti_x005f_doclibrowid,
        ServerRelativeUrl: ifr.data.ServerRelativeUrl,
        ParentServerRelativeUrl: siteSRUrl + "/" + globalThis.libraryNameFull,
        ParentFolderName: "root",
        IndexNumber: folder.IndexNumber,
        IndexSortRef: folder.IndexSortRef,
        ItemType: 1,
      });
  });
 await Promise.all(rootFolderPromises);
```

I need to add the folder to SharePoint and then add another entry in a seperate list which I use to store other data about the item.

I'm assuming that the sp.web.folders.add is not completing before I try and get the folder properties.

What can I do to fix this?  I'm a bit new to all of this so I don't know if I need to have a timeout or maybe a return of some sort.  Or perhaps put some of the actions in a seperate function etc.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:  I am using version 2 of pnp js https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v2/sp/folders/#add

Comment: Which version of PnPJS are you using? I'm not seeing the "add" only "addUsingPath"? https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#add

Comment: Hi,  Sorry, I forgot to mention that.  I am using V2 https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v2/sp/folders/#add

Comment: It seems like you need to split up your functionality, everything is currently in rootFolderPromises. I would take the code where you get the folder properties and put it in another function which can then wait for the folder to be created successfully.

Comment: Ok cool, I will try that out. Thank you.